# Гипотеза

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: "гипотеза о чем-то" или "гипотеза насчет чего-то"? Или есть какой-то третий вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как известно, гипотеза - это буквально научное предположение, поэтому вполне уместно писать "гипотеза о чем-то"

Answer (score 0):

Третий вариант есть. "Гипотеза чего" (гипотеза существования частицы Бога, например).
Но "гипотеза о чем-то"  вполне нормально, если нет возможности сказать "чего" (в силу пояления нанизанного родительного падежа, например). Вот "гипотеза насчет" - это уже слишком разговорное.